# Is there an alternative to fixed-size array for coordinate system?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates

### Situation

I have implemented a random walk algorithm for generating dungeon-like maze. The algorithm have multiple "walkers" each randomly contributing to the same maze. You can have an idea of how the algorithm works by going to this url: https://thomaskerbrat.github.io/procedural-maze/
(If the animation went too fast, reload the page to have a new maze.)

The maze is generated step by step and rendered each time. Red squares represent each walkers as they progress through the map.

In this implementation I have a **fixed-size** array of arrays representing the game's tiles (floor, wall or none). By default, the grid is 64 by 64.

### Problem

When the algorithm reaches an edge I cannot go beyond and the walker stops generating paths.

My question is: *is there a way to replace the fixed-size array of arrays with something not limited by initial dimensions?*

The issue is that I want to perform look-ups to know neighboring cells' content. This is easily done with the fixed-size arrays, I simply access appropriate indexes (checking beforehand that they don't exceed the grid size). But I didn't find a solution on the web.

### Example of my proposed solution

So far, I came up with having a list of the elements I want to place in the grid and keeping a double hash-map for look-ups.

Consider a list of points with the following coordinates in a 10x10 grid:

- A (4,5)
- B (8,2)
- C (4,2)
- D (8,5)
- E (3,7)
- F (3,2)

The corresponding hash-map would map X and Y coordinates to the in-memory objects:

- 3

  - 2 -> F
  - 7 -> E
- 4

  - 2 -> C
  - 5 -> A
- 8

  - 2 -> B
  - 5 -> D

In order to see if a neighboring cell exists or to check its content, I check if the hash-map has the X coordinate as a key (pointing to an other hash-map), if so I'll do the same thing for the Y coordinate to finally find a cell, or not.

So, what do you think? Are you aware of a somewhat "standard" method, or at least well-known method?

Comment: How about using a very large initial array, say 1024x1024, and then cropping it afterwards?

Comment: so you want to create an algorirhm that may never finishes... sounds funny... just replace `array` for `list` and, or use a programming language which arrays are dinamically binded

Comment: You could create a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) representation and let the array grow as large as you like. Your only limitation is memory. Or, if you wanted to overflow to disk, your only limitation is how much disk space you have. I assume you have some conditions under which you will kill the walkers.

Comment: @justhalf The point is not to use a fixed size array.

Comment: @RafaelLima Actually I have a limit to how many paths my walkers can create collectively.

Comment: @JimMischel To my understanding, sparse matrix are fixed size array.

Comment: Then update your understanding. The [Storing a sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix) subtopic describes several representations that are not fixed-sized arrays. For example, the answer you accepted corresponds to the "Coordinate list" described in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @JimMischel You are right, I only read the introduction of the article and I didn't see the point of your link. Please accept my apologies. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is not to use an array, but a set of coordinates to record all positions visited, calculate the span of the walk, and map it to a grid of appropriate size, after the walk:

This solution randomly walks a walker, without constraints on the extent of the walk, then builds a data structure that automatically adjusts to the size of the data; it uses ordered sequences and indices.

1- start your walker at position (0, 0), a tuple, and insert it in the set.
2- walk the walker:
2-1- create a new coordinates tuple for the walker with its new position row +/- 1 and/or column +/-1 for each direction of the step.
2-2- record this new position by inserting it in the set at each step.
3- keep walking until done.
4- generate a grid from the walking positions:
4-1- find the min and max rows and columns to determine the span.
4-3- create a grid of size max-min for both rows and columns.
4-4- populate the visited positions by changing the coordinates of the walk to those of the grid.

If you require the steps in sequence, you can use an ordered set, or a map.
If positions can be visited more than once, you can use a sequence (array, list...) instead, or a mapping to a sequence of time steps if you need to keep track of the order of the visits.

An implementation (python) could look like this:

```
"""
a 2D grid that auto adjusts its size to the data.
coordinates are tuples of integers in the range -1e9 <-> 1e9
"""


class SpanGrid:

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.grid = None
        self.rows = None
        self.columns = None
        self.make_grid()

    def make_grid(self):
        self._find_num_rows_columns()
        self._populate_grid()

    def _find_num_rows_columns(self):
        self.minrow, self.mincol = 1e9, 1e9
        self.maxrow, self.maxcol = -1e9, -1e9
        for row, col in self.coordinates:
            self.minrow = row if row < self.minrow else self.minrow
            self.mincol = col if col < self.mincol else self.mincol
            self.maxrow = row if row > self.maxrow else self.maxrow
            self.maxcol = col if col > self.maxcol else self.maxcol
        self.rows = self.maxrow - self.minrow + 1
        self.columns = self.maxcol - self.mincol + 1

    def _populate_grid(self):
        self.grid = [[None for dummycol in range(self.columns)]
                     for dummyrow in range(self.rows)]
        for r, c in self.coordinates:
            self.grid[r - self.minrow][c - self.mincol] = True

    def __str__(self):
        result = []
        for line in self.grid:
            res = ''
            for pos in line:
                res += str(pos) if pos else ' -  '
                res += ' '
            result.append(res)
        return '\n'.join(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import random
    visited = set()
    offsets = ((1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1))
    start = (0, 0)
    current = start
    visited.add(current)
    for _ in range(100):
        cur_row, cur_col = current
        row_offset, col_offset = random.choice(offsets)
        current = (cur_row + row_offset, cur_col + col_offset)
        visited.add(current)

    grid = SpanGrid(visited)
    print(grid)
```

#### example outputs:

```
 -   True True True True True True  -   
 -   True True True True True True True 
 -   True True True True True True  -   
True True True True True True  -    -   
True True True True True True  -    -   
 -   True True True True  -    -    -   
 -   True  -    -    -    -    -    -
```

`============================================================================`

```
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True  -    -   
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True True True  -   
 -    -    -    -    -   True True  -   True True True True 
True True True True True True True  -   True True True True 
 -   True True True True True True True True True True  -   
 -    -    -   True True True True True  -    -    -    -
```

`============================================================================`

```
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True True True True  -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -   
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True  -    -   True True True  -    -   True True  -    -    -   
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True True  -   True True True  -   True True True  -    -    -   
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True True True True True True True True True  -    -    -    -   
 -   True True  -    -    -    -    -   True  -   True True True  -    -   True True  -    -    -   
True True True True  -    -    -    -   True  -    -   True True  -    -   True True True  -    -   
True True True True  -    -   True True True  -    -    -   True  -    -    -   True True  -    -   
 -    -    -   True True True True  -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True True  -    -    -   
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True True True True 
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True 
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True True 
 -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -   True
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and the proposed solution in OP?

Comment: The OP suggests the use of hash maps, and looking up neighboring cells before stepping; this solution randomly walks a walker, without constraints on the extent of the walk, then builds a data structure that automatically adjusts to the size of the data; it uses ordered sequences and indices.